# Teflon Coating your new car

Tags: paint

While buying a new car, the dealer suggests Teflon coating your car so that the paint shine lasts longer. I know that Teflon is a substance which does not easily attach to any other substance. So is this treatment for real or is this a scam?

-- Update

Did some research on the [DuPont](http://www2.dupont.com/Automotive/en_US/applications/caseStudies/case164.html) site. Found this case study -

> Application Description Have you
>   wished that your new vehicle could
>   stay new looking longer with that
>   glossy “wet look” that turns heads and
>   prompts valet attendants to park you
>   up front?  Until now, that proud, new
>   ownership experience was too often
>   marred by fine swirl marks from
>   cleaning or surface dulling and
>   clouding from exposure to the
>   elements. Today, Ford Motor Company
>   offers a unique, premium paint job
>   that will resist scratching and mars
>   longer than the finish on any other
>   vehicle in the parking lot.

Seems like something which is expensive and done at the time of manufacturing and not at a later stage.

Comment: I like the scene from Seinfeld where Jerry is asking about undercoat and Putty replies "We don't even know what that is". I'd skip it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most dealers offer these coatings and protectants and they are little more than wax (if anything). I always tell the dealer that I don't want any of these coatings and I won't pay for them. They always take the charge off.

There's nothing out there that will keep your finish looking great except regular maintenance. I spent 8 years in the auto body industry and never once saw the "desert protection coating" anywhere but a dealer marketing pamphlet.

Answer (score 3):

It might be okay for awhile, but that stuff eventually might start flaking off.  I had a Monte Carlo where this stuff started coming off.  The paint under it was flat and dull and it looked pretty bad.

Here is a [thread similar to this question](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-chat/1442803/posts) with people that claim that you don't need the coating.

Answer (score 3):

There's no or little Teflon in the coating. Teflon has a melting point of several hunderd degrees Celcius and no one is able to apply that to an ordinary car. ;) Most of these so called enhanced protectors (Waxoyl, Teflon coating, etc.) are no more than some chemical wax-like layer being applied to the car. Protection and gloss is far better with normal waxes from respected brands although both require care (no car wash!) and maintenance.

Comment: I agree Alex,
The real Teflon does have a very high melting point and its not an easy job of applying on a car. Rather it will damage the real paint. Its just a good quality of wax coating. Even for a single application you can also use a clear gloss spray and can apply it yourself on your vehicle. Remember to keep your vehicle in sunlight for an hour to get absorbed naturally. You can easily get a spray of clear gloss from a paint shop for just $3-5.